# JavaFX native launcher for IzPack installation: control InnoSetup/WiX/RPMBuild behavior

Tags: javafx-2, native, java, launcher, izpack

I'm trying to create a native executable launcher with embedded JRE inside for my existing IzPack installation.

Is there any way to control behavior of InnoSetup/WiX/rpmbuild during runtime?

For example, I don't want any "Start Menu" or "Add/Remove Programs" entries to be created during EXE/MSI execution, because this step only extracts IzPack installation and JAR + JRE runtime, while all meaningful setup will be done later by IzPack.

For instance, is there any way to use `*.iss` file for InnoSetup setup.exe build during JavaFX `fx:deploy` target in Ant?

I didn't find any related documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it is impossible.

JavaFX using some pre-defined iss template and currently there is no way to change it. Only few options available to change, all of them are described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference001.htm#CIABIFCI

Comment: You should be able to do it per [Customization Using Drop-In Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#BCGICFDB).